# Let's keep the help center articles updated!

Tags: debate, status-pronto, tradução

Embora a iniciativa seja [status-pronto](/questions/tagged/status-pronto), fique à vontade para fazer edições se quiser melhorar alguma coisa. Vou receber notificações e atualizar o artigo associado da Central de Ajuda.

---

I would appreciate the translation of this question.

---

Earlier this week, my colleagues made several improvements to the closing UX and updated the help center to represent the new interface.

Let's update the help center articles in our community and add translated new strings if needed together!

- [List of the new strings is on Google Docs](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1yaL9EWFUmSZIdqXeydAG3yh5W6kthqSv4QHiS-ei7ns/edit). Please add your translations on [Traducir.win](https://traducir.win/). Please note that although some strings in English have changed, we might want to use our old ones. For example, close reasons.
- Folks edited three help center article:

  - “[Flag posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/flag-posts)” ("[sinalizar publicações](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8300/17539)")
  - “[Cast close and reopen votes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/close-questions)” ("[Votar para suspender ou reabrir](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8301/17539)")
  - “[What does it mean if a question is "closed"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions)” ("[O que significa se uma pergunta está "fechada" ou "pendente"?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8302/17539)")

  Let's try to keep them updated together! Below, in the answers to this question there are the current versions of each article. Answers are marked as wiki. If you see any opportunities for improvement or you find that something is missed, please do not hesitate to make an edit. Once we decide that everything is fine, I’ll update the help center.

If you have any questions or suggestions, please ask them in comments on this post. Thanks! =)

Answer (score 1):

## [sinalizar publicações](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/flag-posts)

#### O que é sinalizar?

Sinalizar é uma forma de chamar a atenção da comunidade para conteúdos inadequados. Os tipos de sinalizadores atualmente implementados são os seguintes:

1. Spam (ou seja, propaganda em massa indiscriminada)
2. Linguagem ofensiva, abusiva ou difamatória
3. Não é uma resposta *(somente para respostas)*
4. Sinalizar para encerrar *(somente perguntas)*

   1. Pergunta duplicada
   2. Descontextualizada (com motivos secundários)
   3. Não está claro o que você está perguntado
   4. Amplo demais
   5. Baseado principalmente em opiniões
5. Qualidade muito baixa (ou seja, não há maneira de salvar a publicação nem mesmo com edições)
6. Outro (requer a ♦ atenção do moderador)

Se você estiver em dúvida sobre qual sinalizador escolher, acesse os links abaixo:

- [Guia de uso para *spam* e *linguagem ofensiva*](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/58035)
- [Guia de uso para *não é uma resposta*](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/81392)
- [Guia para sinalizadores descontextualizados](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/169824)
- [Guia de uso para *qualidade muito baixa*](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/93606)

#### Quando devo sinalizar?

Se acontecer qualquer coisa em nosso site que faça você sentir-se desconfortável ou que, em sua opinião, claramente não deveria estar aqui, *por favor*, sinalize esse conteúdo e chame nossa atenção para ele!

#### Como faço para sinalizar?

Clique no link do <kbd>sinalizador</kbd> abaixo de qualquer publicação e você verá a caixa de diálogo pop-up representada abaixo.

> **Pergunta**
>
> [image: Caixa de diálogo de sinalização para pergunta]

> **Resposta**
>
> [image: Caixa de diálogo de sinalização para resposta]

#### O que acontece quando eu sinalizo algo como *spam* ou *linguagem ofensiva*?

Os sinalizadores de spam e linguagem ofensiva são projetados para eliminar automaticamente publicações verdadeiramente ofensivas por meio da colaboração da comunidade.

- 3 sinalizadores -- a publicação é banida da página inicial.
- 6 sinalizadores -- a publicação é bloqueada, excluída e o proprietário perde 100 pontos de reputação.

Os usuários com [privilégio de Ferramentas do moderador](/help/privileges/moderator-tools) podem ver quantos sinalizadores de linguagem ofensiva uma publicação recebeu e podem optar por sinalizá-la também.

#### O que acontece quando eu sinalizo algo como *requer a ♦ atenção do moderador*?

Será solicitado que você insira um comentário explicando claramente qual é o problema. Após fazer isso, esses sinalizadores para o moderador entram em uma fila especial de alta prioridade visível a todos os moderadores. (Os usuários com privilégio de Ferramentas do moderador não podem visualizar esses sinalizadores.) Levamos muito a sério os sinalizadores para o moderador; você pode ter certeza de que todos eles serão acompanhados!

#### Há alguma forma de remover sinalizadores?

Muitas vezes isso não é necessário, pois sinalizadores de linguagem ofensiva e spam expiram após 48 horas quando os limites não são alcançados.

Retornar uma publicação a um estado anterior reverterá para o número de sinalizadores de linguagem ofensiva dessa revisão específica. Isso permite que o OP (ou outra pessoa com direitos de edição) retorne uma publicação que alguém sinalizou como ofensiva em uma revisão posterior. No entanto, na qualidade de usuário normal, uma vez que você sinalizar uma publicação como ofensiva, não poderá desfazer essa ação.

#### Quantos sinalizadores tenho?

Ao iniciar, você recebe **10** sinalizadores por dia. Esse número pode crescer até **100** sinalizadores por dia:

- Você recebe um sinalizador de bônus a cada 2000 pontos de reputação.
- Você recebe outros sinalizadores de bônus quando sinaliza algo corretamente: um sinalizador de bônus para cada dez sinalizadores úteis líquidos (total de sinalizadores úteis menos os sinalizadores recusados).

Answer (score 1):

## [Votar para suspender ou reabrir](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/close-questions)

#### O que significa encerrar?

Encerrar é um processo de votação democrático no qual a comunidade identifica perguntas que duplicam conteúdos existentes, não podem ser razoavelmente respondidas em seu estado atual ou não deveriam estar no site.

#### Quando devo votar para encerrar uma pergunta?

As perguntas devem ser encerradas por votos pelo encerramento quando:

- são suficientemente semelhantes a outras perguntas existentes e seriam respondidas de modo idêntico.
- são pouco claras, excessivamente amplas ou de outra forma problemáticas para identificar o problema de maneira que possam ser adequadamente respondidas.
- encontram-se suficientemente descontextualizadas, conforme definido na [Central de ajuda](/help/on-topic).

Observe que, uma vez obtida a reputação para votar pelo encerramento, você não deve mais sinalizar para a atenção do moderador para que as perguntas sejam encerradas ou migradas. Será sua responsabilidade votar a partir de então. Consulte também: [Como minha sinalização será alterada quando eu puder votar pelo encerramento?](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/3154/how-should-my-flagging-change-when-i-gain-the-ability-to-vote-to-close)

#### Como faço para votar pelo encerramento de uma pergunta?

O número atual de votos pelo encerramento será exibido abaixo da pergunta, entre parênteses, da seguinte forma:

`encerramento (3)`

Se não houver votos pelo encerramento, simplesmente será exibido:

`encerramento`

Para votar pelo encerramento, ou simplesmente visualizar a contagem atual de votos pelo encerramento e os motivos, clique no link "encerrar" abaixo do corpo da pergunta. Será exibida uma lista de motivos para o encerramento, com as descrições e contagens atuais.

[image: Exemplo de caixa de diálogo de encerramento]

Se você quiser votar nesse momento, use os botões de seleção para especificar um motivo para encerrar a pergunta e, em seguida, clique no botão "Votar pelo encerramento". Se você selecionar "descontextualizada", deverá selecionar outro motivo secundário explicando por que a pergunta está descontextualizada.

- São necessários **5** votos pelo encerramento para superar o limite de encerramento.
- Você pode usar até **24** votos pelo encerramento por dia (50 no Stack Overflow).
- Os votos pelo encerramento perdem a validade sem nenhum efeito após **4** dias caso o limite de encerramento não seja alcançado. Cada novo voto pelo encerramento restaura o contador de tempo, e os votos pelo encerramento só começam a expirar [quando a pergunta alcançar 100 visualizações](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56614/what-happened-here-voted-to-close-4-days-ago-but-no-close-votes-today/97594#97594).

#### O que acontece quando uma pergunta é encerrada?

Uma vez encerrada uma pergunta, ela não aceitará mais novas respostas e as palavras `[em suspenso]` serão anexadas ao título. Após 5 dias, se a pergunta permanecer encerrada, a palavra `[encerrada]` será anexada ao título.

As perguntas encerradas podem ser reabertas por meio de um processo de votação semelhante. O número atual de votos pela reabertura será exibido como `atual` abaixo da pergunta, entre parênteses, da seguinte forma:

`reabertura (3)`

Uma dica de ferramenta exibe o número de votos necessários para a reabertura. Se não houver votos pela reabertura, simplesmente será exibido:

`reabertura`

As perguntas podem passar por vários ciclos de encerramento e reabertura, mas cada usuário individual só pode votar uma vez em cada sentido durante o ciclo.

As perguntas encerradas também podem finalmente ser mescladas com outra pergunta, migradas a outro site de nossa rede ou mesmo excluídas. Uma pergunta encerrada pode ser excluída 48 horas após seu encerramento inicial.

#### Alternativas ao encerramento

Se você não tiver reputação suficiente para votar pelo encerramento, ou se tiver usado todos os seus votos desse dia pelo encerramento, há alternativas:

- Se a pergunta estiver duplicada, publique um comentário com um link para a pergunta original.
- Se a pergunta tiver sérios problemas (por exemplo, se for spam ou ofensiva), [sinalize-a](/help/privileges/flag-posts).

#### Análise de votos pelo encerramento e reabertura

Este nível de privilégio desbloqueia outras duas filas de revisão para [votos pelo encerramento](/review/close) e [votos de reabertura](/review/reopen) para analisar perguntas que podem ter escapado inadvertidamente ou que foram melhoradas e agora devem ser reabertas.

Qualquer publicação que atualmente tiver um voto pelo encerramento ativo *ou* um motivo principal de sinalização idêntico a um voto pelo encerramento será exibida na fila de revisão Votos pelo encerramento. Nessa fila de revisão, os usuários podem votar para encerrar a pergunta, editar a pergunta ou votar para deixá-la aberta. A edição da pergunta ou o número suficiente de votos para deixá-la aberta automaticamente farão com que ela saia da fila, e imediatamente começará a contar o tempo para o vencimento dos votos pelo encerramento (independentemente do número de visualizações). Se a pergunta receber outro voto pelo encerramento após sua expulsão, ela entrará novamente na fila para ser analisada. As perguntas com votos pelo encerramento por duplicação também indicarão as possíveis duplicatas em uma aba localizada na parte superior para facilitar a revisão.

De modo semelhante, a fila de reabertura conterá as publicações que atualmente têm um voto de reabertura ativo. Os usuários podem votar pela reabertura, editar a pergunta (o que inclui um voto de reabertura) ou deixar a pergunta encerrada. Um número determinado de votos para Deixar encerrada fará com que a pergunta saia da fila, e começará o processo de contar o tempo para o vencimento dos votos de reabertura. Naturalmente, um novo voto de reabertura devolverá a pergunta à fila. Da mesma forma, as perguntas que forem editadas durante o período de espera de 5 dias serão automaticamente exibidas na fila de reabertura para serem revisadas. As perguntas que passarem por uma revisão ganharão uma aba extra na parte superior, para que você possa visualizar rapidamente a revisão. Como ocorre na fila de votos pelo encerramento, as perguntas que forem fechadas como duplicadas exibirão as duplicatas nas abas acima.

Answer (score 1):

## [O que significa se uma pergunta está "fechada" ou "pendente"?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions)

#### Por que algumas perguntas estão "pendentes"?

As perguntas que exigem trabalho adicional ou que [não são adequadas para este site](/helpcenter/on-topic) podem ser suspensas pelos membros experientes da comunidade. Enquanto as perguntas estiverem pendentes, não podem ser respondidas, mas podem ser editadas para que se qualifiquem para a reabertura.

As perguntas que forem editadas em até cinco dias de suspensão entrarão automaticamente em uma fila de reabertura para a análise da comunidade. As perguntas que não forem reabertas dentro de cinco dias serão alteradas de `[pendente]` para `[fechada]`.

Cada pergunta fechada ou pendente fornece um motivo que ajuda o autor da publicação original (ou outros membros da comunidade) a saber o que precisa fazer para reabri-la.

Estas são as categorias das perguntas que podem ser fechadas pela comunidade:

- [**duplicada**](/help/duplicates) - o objetivo fundamental de fechar as perguntas duplicadas é ajudar as pessoas a encontrar a resposta correta reunindo todas as respostas em um local

  > Esta pergunta foi feita anteriormente e já tem uma resposta. Se essas respostas não abordarem completamente sua pergunta, edite esta pergunta para explicar de que forma ela difere da pergunta ou faça uma nova pergunta.
- **[fora de escopo](/helpcenter/on-topic)** - cada comunidade decide quais os tópicos específicos que são permitidos ou não, em seu site.

  > Esta pergunta não parece ser sobre $Topic [dentro do escopo definido pela comunidade](/helpcenter/on-topic). Nem sempre é claro quando algo está dentro ou fora do escopo, portanto pode ser necessário, coma a ajuda da comunidade, reformular a pergunta para que ela fique adequada.

  Talvez seja melhor editar a pergunta ou deixar comentários para melhoria se você acredita que a pergunta pode ser reformulada para se adaptar ao escopo.
- **não está claro o que você está perguntando** - às vezes precisamos de mais informações para ajudar a resolver seu problema

  > Esclareça seu problema específico ou acrescente outros detalhes para destacar exatamente o que precisa. Da forma como a pergunta está escrita, é difícil saber exatamente o que você está perguntando.

  Edite sua publicação para ser mais específico sobre o que você está procurando e aborde as preocupações que outros usuários levantarem nos comentários.
- **muito ampla** - se a sua pergunta pode ser respondida por um livro inteiro ou tiver muitas respostas válidas, provavelmente é muito ampla para nosso formato.

  > Ou há muitas respostas possíveis ou boas respostas seriam muito longas para este formato. Acrescente detalhes para reduzir o conjunto de respostas ou isole uma questão que possa ser respondida em poucos parágrafos.
- **principalmente baseada em opiniões** - [as discussões focadas em diversas opiniões](/help/dont-ask) são ótimas, mas não são exatamente adequadas ao nosso formato.

  > Várias perguntas de boa qualidade geram algum grau de opinião com base na experiência de especialistas, mas as respostas a esta pergunta tendem a ser quase que totalmente baseadas em opiniões e não em fatos, referências ou experiência específica.

#### Quem decide que uma pergunta está "pendente"?

Os usuários com reputação de $ReputationRequiredToClose podem votar para fechar até $CloseVotesPerDay perguntas por dia. Quando uma pergunta receber $CloseVotesNeededForClosure votos de fechamento, será marcada `[pendente]` e não aceitará mais respostas. Esses usuários podem votar para reabrir as perguntas do mesmo modo. Cada usuário pode votar para fechar e reabrir uma mesma pergunta apenas uma vez. (Por exemplo, se você votar para fechar uma pergunta que é fechada e depois reaberta, não pode votar para fechá-la novamente.)

Os moderadores podem fechar ou reabrir qualquer pergunta com um único voto.

Para ler mais sobre reabertura de perguntas, consulte ["E se discordar do fechamento de uma pergunta? Como posso reabrir uma pergunta?"](/helpcenter/reopen-questions)

#### Por que algumas perguntas estão "fechadas"?

As perguntas são marcadas como `[pendentes]` pelos primeiros cinco dias após o fechamento para incentivar as edições e melhorias na pergunta. Se uma pergunta for editada pelo autor original do post quando está marcada como `[pendente]`, ela será colocada automaticamente em uma [fila de análise](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/161390/what-are-the-review-queues) para ser considerada para reabertura. Se não for reaberta dentro de cinco dias, o aviso `[pendente]` automaticamente será alterado para `[fechada]`. Do ponto de vista funcional não há diferença entre uma pergunta `[pendente]` e uma `[fechada]`; nenhuma delas pode ser respondida até que seja reaberta, mas tanto uma como a outra permitem comentários, votos e edições.